# H323 Gateway configuration

Tags: cisco, network-core, cisco-voip

I configured a Cisco H323 Gateway between 2 CUCMs connected via Intercluster trunk(non-gatekeeper controlled) Dial peer configuration is :

```
dial-peer voice 10001 voip  
destination-pattern 3971...   
session target ipv4:10.10.10.1    
session transport tcp    
incoming called-number .    
dtmf-relay h245-alphanumeric    
codec g711ulaw    
!   
dial-peer voice 10002 voip   
destination-pattern 2971...    
session target ipv4:10.10.10.2    
session transport tcp    
incoming called-number .    
dtmf-relay h245-alphanumeric    
codec g711ulaw
```

Call entered the gateway and not routed to the destination.

Comment: the call can inter the VG from the two sides but can't out

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

if the call can inter the VG from the two sides but can't out you may need to add the next lines to your configurations :

```
Router(config)# voice service voip 
Router(config-voi-serv)# allow-connections h323 to h323
Router(config-voi-serv)# allow-connections sip to sip
Router(config-voi-serv)# allow-connections h323 to sip
Router(config-voi-serv)# allow-connections
```